# How to create vertical lines between x-values on barplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am currently working on a barplot which looks like this:
[image: The current version]
In order to provide more clarity, I would like to add a vertical line that should point out the separation between the x values. I've drawn an example here:
[image: the desired version]

In order to draw the diagram, I am using the plot function from pandas on the corresponding dataframe:

```py
produced_items.plot(kind='bar', legend=True,title="Produced Items - Optimal solution",xlabel="Months",ylabel='Amount',rot=1,figsize=(15,5),width=0.8)
```

I hoped to find a parameter in matplotlib, that yields the desired behavior, but I didn't find anything, that could help.
Another solution that comes in my mind is to plot a vertical line between each x-value but i wonder if there is a built-in way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try modifying the minor ticks:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator

ax = df.plot.bar()

# set the minor ticks
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(0.5))

# play with the parameters to get your desired output
ax.tick_params(which='minor', length=15, direction='in')
```

Output:

[image]