# How to add edge color to the histogram bins

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I am currently trying to render a histogram using Python's matplotlib. I'm having difficulty drawing vertical lines between each of the bins.

**Here is my current code**

```
plt.figure(figsize=[10, 5])

array = np.random.normal(loc=0, scale=1, size=100)
plt.hist(array, bins=25, color='#0504AA', alpha=0.5)

plt.grid(axis='x', alpha=0.5)
plt.grid(axis='y', alpha=0.5)

plt.xlabel('Value',     fontsize=12.5)
plt.ylabel('Frequency', fontsize=12.5)

plt.xticks(fontsize=12.5)
plt.yticks(fontsize=12.5)

plt.title('Histogram Distribution', fontsize=12.5)
plt.show()
```

**Here is the current output**

[image]

**Here is the desired output**

[image]

Comment: have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65797641/matplotlib-how-to-create-vertical-lines-between-x-values-on-barplot

Comment: Is your intention to add black lines with gaps or overlapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
plt.hist(array, bins=25, color='#0504AA', alpha=0.5,edgecolor ="black", linewidth=2)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qGpu.png